# "java.sql.SQLException: SAVEPOINT _667166fe_13ab4b3e3de__8000 does not exist" exception occur in nested transaction rollback ?

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc

class User {

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws SQLException {
    Connection con = DBConnect.getConnection();
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    System.out.println(con.getMetaData().supportsSavepoints()); // true
    try {
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into emp(emp_id, emp_name, salary, address, contact_number)values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        pstmt.setInt(1, 1);
        pstmt.setString(2, "a");
        pstmt.setDouble(3, 8);
        pstmt.setString(4, "s");
        pstmt.setInt(5, 9);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
        Savepoint sp = con.setSavepoint();
        if (myMethod(con)) {
            /**
             * I want to rollback the nested transaction if any error occur
             */
            con.rollback(sp);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static boolean myMethod(Connection con) throws SQLException {

    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    try {
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into emp(emp_id, emp_name, salary, address, contact_number)values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        pstmt.setInt(1, 2);
        pstmt.setString(2, "G");
        pstmt.setDouble(3, 8);
        pstmt.setString(4, "G");
        pstmt.setInt(5, 10);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

In the above code I want to rollback the nested transaction if any condition would fail . I have created a savepoint just after committing first transaction.I am getting an exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: SAVEPOINT _667166fe_13ab4b3e3de__8000 does not exist
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2928)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1571)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1666)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2988)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:935)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:873)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.rollback(Connection.java:4777)
at com.User.main(User.java:31)
```

I would like to know whether the nested transaction will rollback or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are already calling `con.commit();` before and after(in myMethod() method) `Savepoint sp = con.setSavepoint();`, there is no `savepoint` and hence complaining.

`COMMIT removes all the save points.` Please refer documentation here:

1. [Oracle SAVEPOINT Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/savepoint_statement.htm)
2. [SQLite Save Point](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_savepoint.html)

Please remove the `commit` call, if you want to set a save point.

In the current state of your code, there is no rollback possible as all transactions are committed, if successful.

Comment: If I will not commit the transaction then There is no need of creating save point.In this case I will not commit the transaction if condition would fail.

Comment: @gauravkumar: Save points are logical points which you want to use in case of exceptions say for example, you have step1 and step2 to be executed in sequence in same transaction. Now if you don't use save point, you will rollback both step1 and step2 in case of exceptions. Now if you create a save point after step1, and exception happens in step2, you can rollback to the save point in that case step1 is not rolled back and you may be able to commit step1 ONLY. In your case, you are committing already, then how will you rollback? And if no rollback, how will savepoint help?

Comment: @gauravkumar: In summary, `COMMIT removes all previous savepoints`. Read the documentation here-[SAVEPOINT-COMMIT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/savepoint_statement.htm).

Comment: Thanks ... I was not able to understand the concept of savepoint.Now I got it.